# Passing parameters to javascript function from <div id="container"

Tags: javascript, html

I am just getting to grips with highcharts and really like the look of them. I can get one to be displayed on my web page using the default data but how do pass data from the id to the function.

The function is called here:

```
<div id="containerpie" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

And the function looks like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#containerpie').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    etc etc
```

Am I right in thinking it should be:

```
$(function (var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

But how do I send the variables from the div line?

Comment: Please, finish your question

Comment: Sorry - it was finished but the < symbol stopped it being shown. I have removed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the data attribute, and then capture from the javascript code. e.g.

```
<div id="containerpie" data-param1="val1" data-param2="val2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

And in your javascript:

```
$(function () {
    // Get from the div element
    var val1 = $('#containerpie').data('val1');
    var val2 = $('#containerpie').data('val2');

    $('#containerpie').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
        ...
```

Comment: I have tried this with <div id="containerpie" data-param1="10" data-param2="20" data-param3="30" data-param4="30" etc but it does not work. I don't quite see how this is meant to work.

Comment: html5 introduces the data attribute, see http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much - this looks absolutely what I need and I have followed the instructions but still no joy. I have posted a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170148/using-html5-custom-data-attributes-to-pass-data-from-div-to-javascript

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass parameters like that.

To fill data based on your data-source you must modified "series" section in the body of that function, below:

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
```

Then you can manipulate "data" element with any string you want, for example you want it loaded from database query. You can use json_encode() support for that.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the help. Yes I am getting the data from a database.

Comment: Actually you can pass data this way - it is great. See the answer from Sergio Aristizábal